# Write function to perform action in subset of container

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have two classes B and D.
I can have several types of containers of pointers of B and D. For example

```
std::vector<B *> VecPB;
std::list<D *> ListPD;
```

Assume also that B and D are somehow related in the sense that they have some common memmber functions (to_str, is_valid, is_ok, ..., etc)

Say there is a member function to_str that can be called in each element of B or D to get the string
representation of B or D.
There is also a another member function that can be applied to B or D is_valid().
So I can say for example VecPB.front()->is_valid()

What I want is to be able to write function that prints all the valid elements in a container of type B or D.

For example, I can write:

```
void display_ValidB(const std::vector<B *> & v) {
  for(std::vector<B *>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
  {
    if((*it)->is_valid())
      std::cout << (*it)->to_str() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I can abstract this one more level and use

```
template<typename T>
void display_valid<const std::vector<T *> & v) {
  for(std::vector<T *>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
  {
    if((*it)->is_valid())
      std::cout << (*it)->to_str() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

But now my problem is: 
Is there a way that I don't have to write a template function for each type of container?
I would not want to write a different template function to vector, set, list, etc....

How to generalize this so that the display_function could take a lambda function as an argument so I could write

```
display_function<D>(ListPD, [](const D & d) {return !d->is_ok();});
```

or, something like

```
display_function<D>(listpd.begin(), listpd.end(), [](const d & d) {return !d->is_ok();});
```

I can use up to C++11 but not C++14.

Comment: "templatize" the container as well :)

Comment: Better use a range-based `for`-loop.

Comment: Why not pass iterators, similar to the STL algorithm functions?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie nowadays with range-for it'd be a more lengthy solution. Otherwise you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template parameter `TContainer` for the container, and a template parameter `TF` for a generic predicate.

```
template<typename TContainer, typename TF>
void display_function(const TContainer& v, TF f) 
{
    for(auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(f(*it)) 
        {
            std::cout << (*it)->to_str() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

display_function(std::vector<D>{/*...*/}, [](const D& d){ return d.is_valid(); });
display_function(std::list<B>{/*...*/}, [](const B& b){ return b.is_ok(); });
```

You can pass an unary lambda that returns `bool` for the `TF f` predicate parameter, and any class supporting `.begin()` and `.end()` calls as the `const TContainer& v` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename C>
void display_valid(const C& v) {
   for(auto& item: v) 
     if(item->is_valid())
      std::cout << item->to_str() << std::endl;
}
```

if you wish you can limit the scope of the template arguments with type traits like [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) but that's needed only if you really have to overload the function differently for different kinds of arguments.

If the classes `B`, `D` etc have different methods to validate, then you could add a second template argument for the validation predicate as @VittorioRomeo suggests and supply a lambda or an overloaded function or functor like this:

```
struct Validator {
    static
    bool operator()(const B& b) {
        return b.is_valid();
    }

    static
    bool operator()(const D& d) {
        return d.is_ok();
    }
};
```

Depending on the rest of the code, a lambda- or functor-based solutions may have their pros and cons (e.g. the functor can be made a default template argument and automatically provide necessary validation for all "known" classes).

BTW storing raw pointers in containers demands extra care about object lifetime and memory management. You could consider using smart pointers with containers instead.